# mongoosejs defining complex model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my Json:
    {name:"string",
      nodes: [
        {name:"String", nodes:[]},
        {name:"String", nodes:[]}
      ]
    }

technically each node is an array of objects which have name and nodes as fields and this keeps chaining down. Technically this is a design of a left nav with multiple tree like layer.

I tried a lot of options in mongoose js, however I only return a null array for nodes. How should i define the model so I can return data in this case for nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want here is to define nodes as an array of references to other nodes.

Your schema should look something like this:

```
var Node = new Schema();

Node.add({
    name: String,
    nodes: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Node'}]
});
```

Comment: Would this be a good design if the node are still part of the same collection?

Comment: Definitely, according to the creator of Mongoose, "Populating refs to the same collection is ok. Try it out :)"https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/O2DWcOccm4w

Comment: @ArvinGopi Also, it would be great if you could accept the answer if you found it helpful =). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Stan. I actually modified the collection according to this schema structure and it worked.